# Background color of Toolbar in Lollipop is normal but in Kitkat is white

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar, android-4.4-kitkat

In Lollipop, The background color of toolbar was shown normally, but in KitKat, it was shown as white color.
I don't know why.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

styles.xml-v21

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: because its part of material design which came in lollipop so it wont shown in api  below 22

Answer (score 4):

Try putting your AppBarLayout at the end of you code. Apparently your included layout is overlapping the ToolBar. That happened to me and I fixed it doing that, it just came to my mind. Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: thank you very much, tried different solutions, but this is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base theme in styles.xml with primary colors and other colors colors then set it as parent in styles.xml-v21 for your style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar".

Below is my example :

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_color_light_100</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_white</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBase" />
```

in styles.xml-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBase">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_light_gray</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

should work.

Comment: I followed that code but it's still shown as white.

Comment: @SangHeonKim can i see your style.xml and also your manifest file. Updated version i mean.